Interstitial video ad close take time to moving to the next screen
I have an app that has 2 activities (Main Activity and Ads Activity). The first activity contains a button. Clicking on it will navigate user to another screen. Before navigating to another screen the interstitial video ad shows up. The problem is when I close the Interstitial Video Ads, Activity shows up for 1 - 2 seconds before moving to Main Activity. How to resilve the issue?
public void loadInterstitialShow() {
    // on below line creating and initializing variable for adRequest
    AdRequest adRequest = new AdRequest.Builder().build();

    // on below line we are loading interstitial ads setting ad unit id to it, ads request and callback for it.
    InterstitialAd.load(getActivity(), getString(R.string.admob_view_interstitial_id), adRequest, new InterstitialAdLoadCallback() {
        @Override
        public void onAdLoaded(@NonNull InterstitialAd interstitialAd) {
            mInterstitialAd = interstitialAd;
      
            interstitialAd.setFullScreenContentCallback(
                    new FullScreenContentCallback() {
                        @Override
                        public void onAdDismissedFullScreenContent() {
                            
                            mInterstitialAd = null;
                             startActivity(new Intent(context, MainActivity.class));
                            Log.e("TAG", "The ad dismissed.");
                        }

                        @Override
                        public void onAdFailedToShowFullScreenContent(AdError adError) {
                        
                            mInterstitialAd = null;
                            Log.e("TAG", "The ad failed to show.");
                          startActivity(new Intent(context, MainActivity.class));
                        }

                        @Override
                        public void onAdShowedFullScreenContent() {
                            // Called when fullscreen content is shown.
                            Log.e("TAG", "The ad was shown.");
                        }
                    });

        }

        @Override
        public void onAdFailedToLoad(@NonNull LoadAdError loadAdError) {
            // this method is called when we get any error
            mInterstitialAd = null;
            Log.e("TAG", "ad failed::::" + loadAdError.toString());


        }
    });

}

